# i got this interview question and i am not sure what is best answer When in the lifecycle would you bind to events? in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

When in the lifecycle would you bind to events? in reactjs

Answer (score 4):

Imagine a click handler in a component:

```
import * as React from 'react';

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({ clicked: true });
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}/>;
  }
}
```

Obviously this won't work, because when `handleClick` is called, `this` is not set to the component instance. Now consider these alternatives:

```
render() {
  return <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>;
}
```

With this, you're creating a new version of a function on every render. Same with this:

```
render() {
  return <button onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}/>;
}
```

...so one approach that's a bit more efficient is to bind in the constructor:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({ clicked: true });
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}/>;
  }
}
```

...but that's not universally considered best practice. If you're using `babel` anyway, you can use the ECMAScript proposal for class instance properties:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
  }

  handleClick = e => {
    this.setState({ clicked: true });
  };

  render() {
    return <button onClick={handleClick}/>;
  }
}
```

...which will have `this` bound to the instance automatically.

But in short, the interviewer was probably expecting you to say "in the constructor."

Comment: thanks so much for the answer, you made it clear and simple